# Android gps orientation

Tags: java, android, gps

Is there any why to get the device or phone orientation in degrees without destination location with the `getBearing();` function?

Or can I get the progressing direction any other way?

Comment: What Platform version(s) are we talking about?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Some kind of compass-functionality? That is possible without "destination". You'll have to use the GPS, though. For Display you'll probably want to couple it with the orientation sensor so your needle actually points in the right direction while turning the phone. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yeah bearing is what you want. what have your tried so far? I've found that bearing is reported fine.

Comment: But for bearing need the destonation location. Im just want to know if I on the vehicle the progressing direction

Comment: So then how can I get to my orientation for example 0° mean the North 180° South and then...